# Delphi change the assembly code of a running process

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to change this address `00741FA5` which has `PUSH Test.009E721C`. I would like to change it to `PUSH Test.009E71C8`.

```
procedure Callback;
asm
  PUSH $9E71C8
end;

procedure TForm2.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  PPid :DWORD;
  PProcess : Cardinal;
begin
  GetWindowThreadProcessId(FindWindow(nil,PChar('Test')), @PPid);
  PProcess := OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, False, PPid);

  InjectASM(PProcess, $741FA5, 10, Integer(@Callback), 0);
end;
```

Here is the InjectASM Function (With error checking)

```
function InjectASM(Process: LongWord; InjectAddress, InjectSize, CodeAddress, CodeSize : Integer): Pointer;
var
  CSize, RSize : Integer;
  Replaced : array of byte;
  Jmp : array [0..4] of byte;
  JmpAddress : Integer;
  NopV : Byte;

  I : Integer;
  NBR: ULONG_PTR;
begin
  //InjectSize must be equal or greater than 5, because we need space for our
  //(far) JMP WWXXYYZZ instruction
  //If there's no space, then just inject it in place of few instructions
  if InjectSize < 5 then raise Exception.Create('InjectSize must be equal or greater than 5.');

  //Let's copy replaced code
  SetLength(Replaced, InjectSize);
  for I := 0 to InjectSize - 1 do Replaced[i] := byte(pointer(dword(InjectAddress) + I)^);

  //Now get procedure's size
  if CodeSize < 1 then begin
    CSize := 0;
    while byte(pointer(CodeAddress + CSize)^) <> $C3 do CSize := CSize + 1;
  end else begin
    CSize := CodeSize;
  end;

  //Size of injected code
  RSize := InjectSize + CSize + 5; //5 stand for far jmp back


  //Allocate memory for code
  Result := VirtualAllocEx(Process, nil, CSize, MEM_COMMIT or MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);

  //Write code to allocated memory
  Win32Check(WriteProcessMemory(Process, Result, Ptr(CodeAddress), CSize, NBR));

  //Write replaced code
  Win32Check(WriteProcessMemory(Process, Ptr(Integer(Result) + CSize), @Replaced[0], InjectSize, NBR));

  //Write back jmp
  JmpAddress := (InjectAddress + InjectSize) - (Integer(Result) + CSize + InjectSize) - 5;
  Jmp[0] := $E9;
  Jmp[1] := byte(JmpAddress);
  Jmp[2] := byte(JmpAddress shr 8);
  Jmp[3] := byte(JmpAddress shr 16);
  Jmp[4] := byte(JmpAddress shr 24);
  Win32Check(WriteProcessMemory(Process, Ptr(Integer(Result) + CSize + InjectSize), @Jmp[0], 5, NBR));


  if Win32Check(VirtualProtectEx(Process,pointer(dword(InjectAddress)),5, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, @NBR)) then
  begin
    //Fill the code which we're going to replace with nops
    if InjectSize > 5 then begin
      NopV := $90;
      for I := 5 to InjectSize - 1 do begin
      Win32Check(WriteProcessMemory(Process, Ptr(InjectAddress+I), @NopV, 1, NBR));
      end;
    end;

    //Write jmp to injected code
    JmpAddress := Integer(Result) - InjectAddress - 5;
    Jmp[0] := $E9;
    Jmp[1] := byte(JmpAddress);
    Jmp[2] := byte(JmpAddress shr 8);
    Jmp[3] := byte(JmpAddress shr 16);
    Jmp[4] := byte(JmpAddress shr 24);
    Win32Check(WriteProcessMemory(Process, Ptr(InjectAddress), @Jmp[0], 5, NBR));
  end;

  Win32Check(VirtualProtectEx(Process,pointer(dword(InjectAddress)),5, NBR, nil));
end;
```

but it won't change.
any help please.

the original function can be found here
http://tpforums.org/forum/threads/1428-Delphi-Asm-code-hooking

Thanks,

Comment: Debug into the InjectASM procedure and check the WriteProcessMemory return values. I assume one of them *(or all)* return false. Use GetLastError to get extended error information.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers  i get `Invalid access to memory location` in the InjectASM procedure  `WriteProcessMemory(Process, Ptr(InjectAddress+I), @NopV, 1, NBR);`

Comment: The exception is pretty straightforward, you are not allowed to change that memory range in its current settings. You need to use VirtualProtectEx to change the access to the memory range to writable. Don't forget to change it back to it's default settings afterwards.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers i have update the function above, but when i try to restore the original protection its fail  `Win32Check(VirtualProtectEx(Process,pointer(dword(InjectAddress)),5, NBR, nil))` with this error `The parameter is incorrect'.`

Comment: You also fail to check for errors

Comment: @DavidHeffernan advise me please

Comment: Read the docs and check return values for errors, as documented

Comment: Also, why are you using this InjectASM function. It's just a plain 4 byte mem copy.

Comment: All you need to do is find the 4 bytes that you want to modify and make a single call to WriteProcessMemory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Procedure FuncNewEntry;
begin
  asm
  PUSH $9E71C8 //the new asm code you want to add.
  end;
end;

Function ChangeEntry(PID:Cardinal;TargetOffest:DWORD;FuncProcedure:Pointer):Pointer;
var
  lpNumberOfBytesWritten:ULONG_PTR;
begin
  PID := OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, False, PID);
  Win32Check(WriteProcessMemory(PID, Pointer(TargetOffest), FuncProcedure, sizeof(@FuncProcedure), lpNumberOfBytesWritten));
  CloseHandle(pid);
end;
```

Usage

```
procedure TForm3.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  PPID:Cardinal;
begin
  GetWindowThreadProcessId(FindWindow(nil,PChar('Test')), @PPid);
  ChangeEntry(PPid,$00741FA5,@FuncNewEntry);
end;
```

Comment: This doesn't look good at all. It can leak the process handle. The call to sizeof makes little sense. How many bytes do you think you are writing?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan i know the sizeof is to big, but i dont know i can calculate the sizeof programmatically.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan i try to change it to `sizeof(@FuncProcedure)` and its work fine, this is the right way ? thanks

Comment: There is no right way. You can't do what you think you are doing. And you aren't doing what you think you are doing. This is all wrong.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan do you mean i can't change the asm code for an address with this function `Function ChangeEntry` or i cant do such that thing at all.

Comment: You can't find the length of a function. Your code doesn't do what you think it does.